# Searching for a font with (a different!) special ampersand

Tags: fonts, ampersand

does anyone know what's the font used for the "&" in the affiliation (c) in this paper?
http://arxiv.org/pdf/1102.0284

and in particular how to do it in LaTeX?

thanks in advance

(I can't post images, as I am a new user and the system doesn't allow me)

Comment: You can download the source of arXiv papers using the "Other formats" link on the article page.

Answer (score 5):

That's Computer Modern Text Italic (cmti), accessible using `\mathit`

Comment: `\textit` should work too.  in fact, since the entire affiliation is in italic, nothing special was needed; that form of ampersand is the default there.

Comment: Thanks.
I should have explained better something. I am writing a paper that uses a class for a different journal that that one. And in the affiliations now the font is probably set differently, so I have to change it and only for that letter.
I managed to have a similar result using:
{\fontfamily{ppl}\selectfont \&}
but it's still not exactly that one.
If I use
{\fontfamily{ctmi}\selectfont \&}
I see a "normal" &.
So I was wondering if any of you have an idea of what is the font
that gives that particular ampersand.

thanks again

Comment: There was a typo. Use `{\usefont{OT1}{cmtt}{m}{it} \&}`